# AngularJS Drag and Drop - How to detect what is dragged and where it is dropped?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angularjs-directive

We are currently building our first AngularJS application. One part of the site requires users to be able to drag users into groups. For example, in Google+ circles a user can select another user and drag them into a circle which adds them to that group.

We understand that we must create a directive to achieve this, and have come up with the following:

```
var DragDrop = angular.module('ajs.Directive.dragDrop', []);

DragDrop.directive('myDrag', function () {
return {

    link: function(scope, elt, attrs) 
    {      
       // scope.obj.outer = "Updated on link";            
        elt.draggable({revert:"invalid"});            
        elt.droppable({        
            //accept: function( d ) { return true; },                
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                return scope.$apply(function () {
                    alert("hello")
                    scope.inner = 'Dropped';                        
                   // scope.obj.outer = 'Updated on drop';                    
                });                
            }            
        });          
    }        
}
});
```

This is allowing us to drag our contacts around. However, we are struggling to find out how to drop a contact into a group, specifically how to detect the element ID of what has been dragged and the element ID of where it has been dropped.

Finally, using the example above when you drag an item the item stays in the new position, but we require it to return to its normal position.

We have tried `revert:"invalid"` within the elt.droppable, but that hasn't worked.

As a quick note, we cannot use jQuery as these items are within an ng-repeat. 
 I am led to believe that a directive is the only solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out: http://ganarajpr.github.io/angular-dragdrop/ 
It might be what you are looking for without the need to reinvent the wheel. 
The source code is available, so you can always improve.

Comment: The link above no longer works.

Based on contributors I think this is the new one for those interested:

https://github.com/angular-dragdrop/angular-dragdrop